# Could you please let me know, if there are any temples in south India which belong to Nimbarkacharya or Vishnuswamy acharyas sampradayas?

Tags: vaishnavism

Could you please let me know, if there are any temples in south India, which belong to Nimbarkacharya or Vishnuswamy acharyas sampradayas.